# easier way to get page params in nested components in next.js app router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, app-router

I have lots of nested components in my next.js application.

And for getting translations i rely on the `params.lang`.

Now i have drill this to every single component.

I know there are hooks, but i want to render them as server components.

Is there any workaround to avoid prop drilling and get access to `params.lang` inside NESTED server components?

```
import { getDictionary } from "@/get-dictionary";
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  link: string;
};

const ShareButton = (props: Props) => {

    // something here to get the params.lang without relying on props?
    const locale = ? 

    const dictionary = await getDictionary(locale)

  return <div>ShareButton</div>;
};

export default ShareButton;
```

Comment: Did you come with any solution? i am facing same problem, i dont want to nest lang everywhere lol, but there is no other solution yet if you want to switch to dynamic rendering of components and use useCookies

Answer (score 0):

You can store the params in cookies which can easily acess from anywhere by importing

`import { cookies } from "next/headers"`

Reference : [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies)

Comment: downside is this will switch it to use dynamic rendering, if im not wrong

Comment: You are not. I am facing same problem and i think only solution is to have nested props everywhere :/